# How to create a Lexis diagram with cases and person-years?

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataset where each row corresponds to one person and has information about the person's date of birth and date of death. The dataset includes who have died in 2005-2010 at the ages 0-18. I'm trying to plot a Lexis diagram with age as the y-axis and calendar time as the x-axis and I want to show the cases and person-years of each triangle such as in the diagram below I found from an [article](https://bendixcarstensen.com/APC/Carstensen.2007a.pdf).

[image]

I found this example code that uses the `Epi` package to create a Lexis diagram with person-years calculated with the function `N2Y`.

```
# Danish population at 1 Jan each year by sex and age
data( N.dk )
# An illustrative subset
( Nx <- subset( N.dk, sex==1 & A<5 & P<1975 ) )
# Show the data in tabular form
xtabs( N ~ A + P, data=Nx )
# Lexis triangles as data frame
Nt <- N2Y( data=Nx, return.dfr=TRUE )
xtabs( Y ~ round(A,2) + round(P,2), data=Nt )
# Lexis triangles as a 3-dim array
ftable( N2Y( data=Nx, return.dfr=FALSE ) )

# Calculation of PY for persons born 1970 in 1972
( N.1.1972 <- subset( Nx, A==1 & P==1972)$N )
( N.2.1973 <- subset( Nx, A==2 & P==1973)$N )
N.1.1972/3 + N.2.1973/6
N.1.1972/6 + N.2.1973/3
# These numbers can be found in the following plot:

# Blue numbers are population size at 1 January
# Red numbers are the computed person-years in Lexis triangles:
Lexis.diagram(age=c(0,5), date=c(1970,1975), int=1, coh.grid=TRUE )
with( Nx, text(P,A+0.5,paste(N),srt=90,col="blue") )
with( Nt, text(P,A,formatC(Y,format="f",digits=1),col="red") )
text( 1970.5, 2, "Population count 1 January", srt=90, col="blue")
text( 1974.5, 2, "Person-\nyears", col="red")
```

However, I don't know how to manipulate my dataframe to be able to use the function and in addition, it doesn't show the number of cases in each triangle. Here's an example dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(40)

df <- data.frame(
  Id = seq(1, 100, by = 1),
  DateOfBirth = sample(seq(as.Date("1990-01-01"), as.Date("2007-01-01"), by = "days"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  DateOfDeath = sample(seq(as.Date("2005-01-01"), as.Date("2010-12-31"), by = "days"), 100, replace = TRUE)
)

df_filtered <- df %>%
  mutate(AgeAtDeath = round(as.numeric(DateOfDeath - DateOfBirth) / 365.25, 1)) %>%
  filter(AgeAtDeath >= 0 & AgeAtDeath <= 18)

print(df_filtered)
```